# Infinite loop with Angular expression binding with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am developing a basic Angular app which reads a feed.

I return in the index.html the value that the controller got clicking this button

```
<button ng-click="loadFeed()">Load News</button>
```

The problem is if I try to do just this:

```
{{loadFeed()}}
```

It goes into an infinitive loop.

Controllers.js:

```
myApp.controller("FeedCtrl", ['$scope','FeedService', function ($scope,Feed) {    
$scope.feedSrc = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss";

$scope.loadFeed=function(){        
    Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedSrc).then(function(res){
        $scope.feeds=res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
    });

}
}]);

myApp.factory('FeedService',['$http',function($http){
return {
    parseFeed : function(url){
        return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
    }
}
}]);
```

I am sorry, I am very new with AngularJS. I have seen another similar topic but I can't resolve my problem.

Comment: An issue might be that loadFeed() does not return anything. Nothing to display. Maybe put {{feeds}}, and call $scope.loadFeed() in your controller to initialize the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I dont get it sorry. feeds is only filled inside loadFeed right now, so I cant call it before calling loadFeed, where do you mean to call $scope.loadFeed()?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is ng-init? What happens if you do {{loadFeed()}} is that it gets called on every digest cycle, which will make it freak out at you. ng-init="loadFeed()" in your button would call it once, and the {{feeds}} would be populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first **$digest** cycle gets fired, your {{loadFeed()}} expression gets evaluated. This produces a call to your function parseFeed, which uses $http. Now, and here is the reason of your issue, the last thing Angular does in an ajax request through $http, is to call **$rootScope.$apply()**. This fires another $digest cycle, which causes your expression to be evaluated once again, which triggers another $rootScope.$apply(), and you can already see the infinite loop going on here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. With this in mind, what worked for me was the ng-init that Zack Argyle said.